# Issue htaccess redirecting www to non www

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, redirect

We are running a Magento website and having issue with redirecting www to non-www. Here is part of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I write: www.xyz.com, then it successfully redirects to xyz.com

But if I write: **www.xyz.com/contact-us**, it redirects to **www.xyz.com/index.php**

What is wrong here? I guess the line `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` is not getting executed.

Comment: Try changing `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]` to: `RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQEUST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Test your rule in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and see if problem still shows up.

Comment: Hi hjpotter92, your solution is not working